# How to populate a ListView in Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have a Web Api that retrieves data from SQL database. I need to consume web api in xamrin for android. I am not sure how to call the GET and Post methods based on button click event. Right now with the code I have written, when I click the button to populate the list, I am getting an empty screen in the App. My API is working fine in Postman, but I don't know how to make it work on Xamarin Android App.

I have created a separate Library in my solution which has my Models and API Service class.

**Web API Get List method**

```
// GET: api/Books
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/books")]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
  IEnumerable<BookDTO> books;
  books = from b in db.Books
    select new BookDTO()
    {
       Id = b.Id,
       Title = b.Title,
       AuthorName = b.Author.Name
    };
       return Ok(books);
 }
```

**API Service class**

```
public static async Task<BookDTO> GetBooks()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    var msg = await client.GetAsync(url);

    if (msg.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        using (var stream = await msg.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var str = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BookDTO>(str);
                return obj;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
static readonly List<string> _bookTitles = new List<string>();
private ListView _list;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    // Get the button from the layout Resource and attach an event to it
    Button getBooks = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.GetBooks);
    _list = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);


    getBooks.Click += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        var books = await BooksApiService.GetBooks();
        ShowTitles(books);
    };
}
    private void ShowTitles(BookDTO books)
    {
        _bookTitles.Clear();
        foreach (var book in books.Title)
        {
            _bookTitles.Add(book.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Web API method's return type is `IEnumerable<BookDTO>`. This means that you are returning an IEnumerable List of books to the client app.
Make these slight changes:

**API Service class**

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<BookDTO>> GetBooks()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
```

Change the return type of your Task to `IEnumerable<BookDTO>` as shown above.

```
if (msg.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        using (var stream = await msg.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var str = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<BookDTO>>(str);
                return obj;
            }
        }
    }
```

Change the type to be deserialized to, from `BookDTO` to `IEnumerable<BookDTO>` as shown above.

**MainActivity.cs**

```
 private void ShowTitles(IEnumerable<BookDTO> books)
    {
       ...
        /*Change this block accordingly.*/
        foreach (var book in books)
        {                 
            _bookTitles.Add(book.Title.ToString());
        }    
      ...
    }
```

The **ShowTitles()** should take `IEnumerable<BookDTO>` as a parameter, since you might want to iterate through each book and retrieving the respective **Title** and adding that to the **_bookTitles** list.

```
getBooks.Click += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        /*This is will work, but it's not recommended. I'll update it later.*/
        var books = await BooksApiService.GetBooks();
        ShowTitles(books.Result);
    };
```

However, the section above will remain as is since you've used the **var** type which means the compiler will determine the explicit type of the variable, based on the usage.

Comment: In the `ShowTitles(books);`, I get this error message `Cannot convert from system.threading.tasks.task<system.collections.Generic IEnumerable> to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check and let me know how it goes.

Comment: It took away the error message. But I am still getting an empty screen when I click on the button. I guess I will have to take a deeper look into this issue.

Comment: I noticed you removed the adapter part, could you return it? I doubt maybe that's the problem. You can also put a breakpoint on  `return obj` and inspect it if it actually has the items. Don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> My API is working fine in Postman, but I don't know how to make it work on Xamarin Android App.

The problem is, on server side, you return an `IEnumerable<BookDTO>` object. But on Client side, you deserialize it into a `BookDTO` object using `var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BookDTO>(str);`.

Please try deserialize it into an `IEnumerable<BookDTO>` with `var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<BookDTO>>(str);`

If the problem still persists, please debug to check what the `str` is by `var str = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();`